# JS await throws an error in a browser console

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt to develop a client for my laravel project.

In the login.vue component I have the following JS code

```
import Form from 'vform'

export default {
  head () {
    return { title: this.$t('login') }
  },

  data: () => ({
    form: new Form({
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }),
    remember: false
  }),

  methods: {
    async login () {
      let data;

      // Submit the form.
      try {
        const response = await this.form.post('/api/login');
        data = response.data;
      } catch (e) {
        return;
      }

      // Save the token.
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/saveToken', {
        token: data.token,
        remember: this.remember
      });

      // Fetch the user.
      await this.$store.dispatch('auth/fetchUser');

      // Redirect home.
      this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to submit the login form with wrong email and password values I see an error message in a browser console.

For example:

```
POST http://laravel.local/api/login 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Please note that I'm using try catch that catches all errors on the following call.

```
const response = await this.form.post('/api/login');
```

Is this really issue with async/await usage?
How can I get rid of that error in the browser console?

If you need some more info from me do not hesitate to ask it.

Comment: what error is thrown in the browser console? oh, wait, it's not a javascript error being thrown, it's a request showing the status of 422 that concerns you?

Comment: The browser will automatically log any HTTP requests that fail. It has nothing to do with `async`/`await`.

Comment: @skirtle is there any way to get rid of them? I don't wont a user to see such errors.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to stop them being logged. Users will not see the errors unless they have the Developer Tools open. `console.clear()` comes close but even that can be overridden within the settings.

Comment: It looks like you can hide them locally by opening the console settings (click the cog icon) and checking 'Hide network'. You can't make users do that though.

Comment: Thanks guys! So as I understand it's impossible to get rid of them.. I wanted to hide them from all users not just from me.